# Why is Azure devops delegated permission asking for admin consent when the portal says it is not required?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to acquire azure devops token with Itokenacquisition of Microsoft identity web library. I am able to generate the token when scope is present in enabletokenacquisitiontocalldownstreamapi In startup file And when I am already logged in to the app. The moment I log out of the app and log in again it asks for admin consent. Not sure about the behaviour. While signing in for the second time it includes ado scope.

Answer (score 0):

> Use token cache serializers,in web apps and web APIs.They provide
> distributed database or cache system to store tokens.

> When you acquire an access token using the Microsoft Authentication Library for .NET
> (MSAL.NET), the token is cached. When the application needs a token,
> it should first call the `AcquireTokenSilent` method to verify if an
> acceptable token is in the cache.

Refer [Acquire a token from cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-acquire-token-silently) for details regarding to AcquireTokenSilent.

- Check these:

1. In startup.cs file make sure you add  `.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();` in the ConfigureServices() method:
   **Example:**

```js
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

public class Startup
{
 const string scopesToRequest = "user.read";
  
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
   // code before
   services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration)
             .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { scopesToRequest })
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
   // code after
  }
  // code after
}
```

2. In the Configure() method add  `app.UseAuthentication();`

> `AddInMemoryTokenCaches` takes an optional parameter of type
> `MsalMemoryTokenCacheOptions` that enables you to specify the duration
> after which the cache entry will expire unless it's used.

For more details refer [msal-net-token-cache-serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization?tabs=aspnetcore)

- You can specify the lifetime of an access, SAML, or ID token issued
  by Microsoft identity platform--Refer: [Configure-token-lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes)

3. You may check if you are passing `prompt=consent` parameter in authentication request. You may **NOT** include that parameter.

**References:**

1. [How to create a .NET Core API that accepts authenticated requests from a Power App](https://cmatskas.com/create-a-protected-api-that-calls-in-ms-graph-on-behalf-of-a-power-app/)
2. [AD-permissions-and-consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent)
3. [permissions-and-consent#openid-connect-scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#openid-connect-scopes)
4. [OAuth Permissions in Azure AD & MSA](https://identitydocs.azurewebsites.net/static/futureoverview/permissions.html)